# what does this replacement statement in perl mean =~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg?

Tags: perl

I know that `=~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg` replace the extra separating spaces with blank but what does `$1` and `seg` means?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: @Mat The documentation on modifiers is pretty poor though. Only `s` is mentioned in perlre.

Comment: @MaryamSani That is three modifiers, `s`, `e` and `g`.

Comment: [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is relevant as well, and contains some discussion of all switches

Comment: @TLP: `s` and `g` are in there. `e`'s hidden in `perlop` though. Probably because it stands for "evil".

Comment: @Mat I've always thought modifiers should be described in a more accessible fashion. `ee` is "extra evil".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` refers to the first capture group.  It'll be whatever `(.)` matched.

`seg` is a bunch of regex flags:

- `s` treats the input as a `s`ingle line.  It tells `.` to also match `\n` (which it normally doesn't).
- `e` treats the replacement pattern as a Perl `e`xpression.  Not sure exactly what good it does here, since `s//` already understands `$1`.
- `g` means to do this replacement `g`lobally (ie: everywhere it appears in the string, as opposed to just the first occurrence).

Answer (score 5):

This is some attempt to remove whitespace, although it is slightly irregular, and I am not sure if that is intentional.

```
s/(.)      # match a single character, capture string into $1
  \s       # match a single whitespace
 /         # replace with
 $1        # the captured string from above
 /seg      # use these modifiers on the substitution
```

- `s` changes the behaviour of the wildcard character `.` to also match newlines
- `e` causes the replacement to be evaluated as Perl code. In this case, it has no effect, because it will simply eval a string to a string.
- `g` for global, means the match is performed as many times as possible, instead of just once, which is default.

The behaviour of this substitution is to remove single whitespaces, which might be an attempt to turn a string `a foo bar` into `afoobar`. However, in the case of multiple consecutive whitespace, it will just remove every other, since `.` will then match a whitespace. So `a foo  bar` will become `afoo bar`. To remedy that, one can add a quantifier to the `\s` character class and allow it to match multiple times: `\s+`.

But then again, if we do that, we might as well skip checking for `.` and do `s/\s+//g`. If the intent is to only remove whitespace that follows non-whitespace, it would be more prudent to use `\S` (non-whitespace) instead of `.`, like so: `s/(\S)\s/$1/sg`.

So as I said, it is a somewhat odd substitution.